# Следует ли группировать переменные в си в начале функции?

Tags: c

Где правильнее писать переменные в си? В начале функции группировать или там, где потребуется? c11 позволяет везде писать, но мне, как перфекционисту очень важно знать, хотел бы услышать ваше мнение по этому вопросу.

Comment: В С нельзя объявлять переменные в середине функции.

Comment: @arrowd, в c11 можно

Comment: Переменные должны инициализироваться. Если 'писать' переменные заранее, то об инициализации можно и забыть. А потом долго отлаживаться.

Comment: чем плох такой вариант  `char *string = NULL; string = (char *) malloc(2 * sizeof(char));` ??

Comment: Если «услышать мнение», то вопрос следует закрыть как не имеющий объективного ответа

Comment: @andreymal одни советуют не теряться в 90х, вторые говорят, что лучше группировать, так как писать код?

Comment: @ast «Пишите там, где удобнее вам» :)

Comment: @andreymal https://habrahabr.ru/company/inoventica/blog/275685/ """Столкнувшись с программированием на С, очень важно не застрять на уровне «истин, усвоенных в 80-х/90-х»."""

Answer (score 1):

Пишите там, где удобнее вам.

Мне, например, удобнее, когда объявление переменной поближе к ее использованию - чтоб далеко глазами не бегать, когда нужно посмотреть, что это...

Если работаете в команде - то там, где решено командой (или руководством :))

Comment: если я буду писать в начале функции, это никак не повлияет на производительность программы?

Comment: Нет, никак не повлияет.

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно группирую переменные в начале функции/метода.

Но дело тут не в Си, а в том, что за переменными в таком случае легче следить и можно вовремя понять, когда следует выделить новый метод/класс.

Архитектура не распыляется по экрану, поэтому легко понять, какие данные обслуживает код, следует ли его рефакторить.

Answer (score 1):

Как писал когда-то в своей книге "Мифический человеко-месяц" Ф. Брукс --

> "Покажите мне свои блок-схемы и спрячьте таблицы, и я ничего не пойму.
>   Покажите мне таблицы, и блок-схемы мне не понадобятся – все будет
>   очевидно и так."

В отношении структуры программы это означает, что ключевые для понимания логики алгоритма переменные следует располагать и описывать комментариями рядом (в одном блоке). Тогда читатель сможет одним взглядом охватить их и осознать связь между хранимыми значениями и логикой потока управления в алгоритме.

Если алгоритм естественным образом делится на стадии, в которых появляются новые, "ключевые" для них переменные, то описывайте их в начале каждой стадии.

Впрочем, поскольку программа обычно состоит из функций небольшого размера, то такие переменные (по крайней мере часть из них)  естественным образом становятся локальными для функции.

А вот временные, вспомогательные переменные, лучше размещать непосредственно в том месте, где они первый раз появляются в коде. Вполне возможно, что в этом месте как раз окажутся и фигурные скобки, которые ограничат область видимости (компилятором) этих переменных.